# Input and confirmation modal

Tags: angular

I have a 10-input form. I added button cancel which is activating => confirmation modal which pop up when all input are filled. But I must do this is such way that modal will pop-up from 2 inputs are filled up ? Any suggestion? help articles? Angular

```
 <app-task-form #form [draftInput]="data"></app-task-form>

 <button mat-flat-button (click)="clickTwo(!form.valid)" i18n="@@CancelButton">
      Cancel
    </button>

 clickTwo(result: boolean): void {
    if (result == false) {
      this.closeModal()
    }
    else {
      this.dialogRef.close();
    }
 }
```

If user will input two fields and will press button modal shoud pop-up. If inputs are empty after pressing button form should close.

Answer (score 0):

Krzysztof. Perhaps your form has a `FormGroup` interface, you can access to all controls of this form by calling method `getRawValue()` or just get the value of property `value`, like `this.form.value`. In both cases you'll get object with interface

```
value/getRawValue: {
  [key: string]: any;
}
```

Where `key` is control name and `any` value of that control. So, you can iterate through this object via `Object.keys` or `for in` loop, and check is in that object at least 2 "keys/controls" with some values. Hope it will help you. If your question is about something else, please clarify the question.

Comment: ``
<button mat-flat-button (click)="clickTwo(this.form.value)" i18n="@@CancelButton">
      Cancel
    </button>

clickTwo(form: Przetarg): void {
    console.log(form)

    for (let index = 0; index < Object.keys(form).length; index++) {

      if (Object.keys(form).length > 4) {


        console.log("Function : true")
        // this.closeModal()
      }
      else {
        console.log("Function : false")
      }

    }
}
``
This loop is not working for me :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<button mat-flat-button (click)="clickTwo(this.form.value)" i18n="@@CancelButton">
      Cancel
    </button>

clickTwo(form: Przetarg): void {
    console.log(form)

    for (let index = 0; index < Object.keys(form).length; index++) {

      if (Object.keys(form).length > 4) {


        console.log("Function : true")
        // this.closeModal()
      }
      else {
        console.log("Function : false")
      }

    }
}
```

This loop is not working for me :(

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO. Actually this is not an answer. You can comment out if you want to ask about answers.

Comment: This was helpful but Istruggle with one thing. If fields are filled in form I see confiramtion modal but I have 21 inputs and problem is with one input I see this => TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id') I asked about senior dev and he also had problem with this (person who bought this problem in mu opinion have mental issues). So how avoid this if all inputs are empty how close main modal :(  Is any solution in html something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, @krzysztofbojarczuk. You made it in a wrong way. Let's fix it.

```
public clickTwo(form: Przetarg): void {
    if (Object.keys(form).length > 4) { 
    // First of all, if you need to check form for amount of fields/controls, this condition should be here but not inside loop. So this "if" just checks if your form has more than 4 controls, but doesn't check is these controls are filled or not.

      let counter = 0;

      Object.keys(form).forEach((key: string) => {
        // To iterate through the object keys we use 'Object.keys(): string[]' method that returns an array of 'keys: string', so we get names of object properties in the array, and we can iterate through the array with '.forEach()' method.

        if (form[key]) {
        // Here we are checking for value in object property. If value exist - not empty string, or undefined, or null, or false. Then we add 1 to a counter.

          counter = counter + 1;
        }
      });

      if (counter >= 2) {
        console.log(`Congrats! 2 or more fields filled in your form. We should show a confirmation modal!`);
        // this.closeModal();
      } else {
        console.log(`User didn't fill at least 2 fields. We can remove this "else" statement if we don't need to do any actions in this case.`);
      }
    }
}
```

I hope it was helpful. If yes, please, vote for this answer .

Comment: This was helpful but Istruggle with one thing. If fields are filled in form I see confiramtion modal but  

I have 21 inputs and problem is with one input  I see this => TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')

I asked about senior dev and he also had problem with this (person who bought this problem in mu opinion have mental issues).

So how avoid this is all inputs are empty how close main modal :(